# Is there an advantage to using a point-free identity function instead of a wildcard?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

If a function has a case that will result in returning the input as-is, is there anything to be gained by using a point-free `id` for that case?

Example:

```
-- First way, use some symbol as wildcard
myFunc :: Int -> SomeData -> SomeData
myFunc 0 _ = _
myFunc ...

-- Second way, point-free `id`. Is this more efficient?
myFunc :: Int -> SomeData -> SomeData
myFunc 0 = id
myFunc ...
```

One standard function where I thought this might be used is `drop` since `drop 0` is effectively `id`. But if you look at the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-List.html#drop), it is not point free (there is `drop 0 xs = xs` ... you have to scroll down a little to see the definition; look for `drop (I# n#) ls`). I suspect it can't matter much if `drop` doesn't make use of it.

Edit: Actually [it looks like equations with differing numbers of arguments is disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936002/567620) by the case-expansion method for translating multiple-equation function definitions.

So if you opted for this route, you'd have to make sure all the remaining equations for the function are also definable in the same point-free style -- which is highly unlikely for most functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GHC, there can be a difference. Which is better will depend on the situation. Specifically, a function is only inlined by the optimizer if it is "fully applied". So in the first formulation, if you were to do something like

```
fooThing (myFunc 0)
```

then (unless some other optimizations happen first), GHC will produce a closure representing `myFunc 0` and then apply it once `fooThing` decides to do so. If you use your `id`-based implementation instead, GHC will translate the above to

```
fooThing id
```

Comment: Another place where I wonder about the difference is unit testing, or QuickCheck-like things. If you replace with `id` it might be possible to write a unit test that is more like a law: "`myFunc 0` doesn't change anything ever ..." or something like that, which could be proven via `id` but it's not clear to me what it would do in the other case.