# Why must equations of a function in Haskell have the same number of arguments?

Tags: haskell, arguments, standards

Sometimes it can be useful in Haskell to not saturate the arguments from a type in the equation of a function. As in the following example:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f _ = id
```

However, when a function is defined with more than one equation. At least GHC seems to demand that all equations have the same number of arguments. For example the following is **not** allowed:

```
g :: Int -> Int -> Int
g 0 = id
g x y = x * y
```

To me this seems like a reasonable definition though. What is the reason that this is not the case?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745597/defining-a-function-by-equations-with-different-number-of-arguments).