# Why can't I make Either instance of Functor using id in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, currying

When making my custom `Either`, and `Functor`, just to understand clearer types and typeclasses, I found the following situation:

**`Functor`**

```
module Functor (Functor, fmap) where

import Prelude hiding(Functor, fmap)

class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

**`Either`**

```
module Either(Either(..)) where
import Prelude hiding(Either(..), Functor, fmap)

data Either a b = Left a | Right b deriving(Show)

instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
```

The code showed above compiles fine but, if I change it to use `id`, it doesn't compile:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
  fmap _ = id
```

Why?? Did I miss something? The following code also doesn't work:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
  fmap f all@(Left x) = all
```

... This seems to me very strange because the code showed below compiles:

```
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)

test :: Shape -> String
test (Circle _ x) = show x
test all@(Rectangle _ x) = show all ++ " - "++ show x
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The first case with `id` is very well explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745597/defining-a-function-by-equations-with-different-number-of-arguments). By the way, be sure to take note of and mention in your questions the specific errors you get - it makes it easier both for you and for answerers to find answers.

Comment: Great point, I will keep it

Comment: If you're interested in point-free expressions, you might think this definition cute: `fmap = either id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do boils down to this:

```
f :: Either a Bool -> Either a ()
f (Right _) = Right ()
f left = left
```

with error:

```
foo.hs:3:7:
    Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘()’
    Expected type: Either a ()
      Actual type: Either a Bool
    In the expression: left
    In an equation for ‘f’: f left = left
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

`left` is bound to the function argument. So the type checker knows it's of type `Either a Bool`. Then it's used as the return value. We know from the type `f :: Either a Bool -> Either a ()` that the return value must be of type `Either a ()`. If `left` is a valid return value, it's type must match the return type of `f`. So `Either a ()` must be equal to `Either a Bool`; it is not, so the type checker rejects the program.

In turn, it's basically the same problem as this:

```
λ let l = Left () :: Either () ()
l :: Either () ()

λ l
Left ()
it :: Either () ()

λ l :: Either () Bool

<interactive>:10:1:
    Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘Bool’
    Expected type: Either () Bool
      Actual type: Either () ()
    In the expression: l :: Either () Bool
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = l :: Either () Bool
```

We gave `l` a binding and a type, then tried to use it as a different type. That's invalid (and feeding it through `id` wouldn't change its type either). Even though `Left ()` is also valid *source code text* for a value of type `Either () Bool`, that doesn't mean that a particular value known to be of type `Either () ()` that could be defined with the source text `Left ()` can be used as if it were of type `Either () Bool`.

If you had a polymorphic value, you could do this:

```
λ let l = Left ()
l :: Either () b

λ l :: Either () ()
Left ()
it :: Either () ()

λ l :: Either () Bool
Left ()
it :: Either () Bool
```

Note that the original `l` value here was polymorphic in `b`; it can be used as an `Either () b` for *any* b.

But your `fmap` case is subtly different. The **function** `fmap` is polymorphic in the `b`, but the value of its argument is "within the scope of the polymorphism"; at the point you have your argument the type `b` has been chosen to be some specific type *by the caller of fmap*, so it's "some unknown type that could by anything" rather than "any type I feel like choosing". There is no way to somehow turn a value of type `Either a b` into a value of type `Either a c`, so you have to extract the `a` value and then create an `Either a c` containing it.

Comment: Your explanation was really amazing, made me understand better how Haskell controls types. By the way, is there any motive which the Haskell makers didn't make it analyse the __given__ value, to find out whether it could be of the type of the return type? I think this approach is more straight forward,  although I understood why the given program doesn't compile. Shouldn't Haskell be the most simple way possible for programmers?

Comment: @FtheBuilder Primarily because we use types to enforce invariants, and so we don't like when things are done behind our backs to our types. A comparable, if simpler, situation is how there is no implicit casting of numbers in Haskell. In any case, your implicit conversion would be of limited use, as it could only work when you pattern match on `Left`. There is no total function `Either a b -> Either a c` ("total" here is the technical term for "works in all cases").

Comment: @duplode Could you please explain better this passage: "Primarily because we use types to enforce invariants, and so we don't like when things are done behind our backs to our types.", maybe saying the same thing with different words

Comment: @FtheBuilder The point is you can give very strong guarantees about how Haskell functions behave based *only* on types. That goes from knowing that for *any* `Functor` if `fmap` follows `fmap id = id` then can't do anything but change the values within the functor, to capturing very general concepts merely by clever choices of type classes to fill in a signature, and to designing complex libraries that can't be used in a wrong way without causing a type error. If types are used like that, implicit conversions can only lead to bugs and confusion. That's why you don't see them in Haskell.

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at the type of fmap specialized for the `Either` functor:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
```

As we can see from this, in `fmap f all@(Left _)`, the type of `all` is `Either e a`. This doesn't match the intended result type `Either e b` prescribed by the signature of `fmap`, so `fmap f all@(Left _) = all` is not well-typed.

Similarly for the case using `id`.

Comment: I understood your answer partially, but I still think it is strange, because (correct me if I am wrong), returning `Left x` instead of `all` would also be of type `Either e a`, they are the same thing... I am trying to think the simplest way possible

Comment: No, you are wrong. If `x :: e`, then `Left x :: Either e c` for any choice of `c`. If you set `c ~ b`, you get `Left x :: Either e b`.

Comment: @FtheBuilder `id` has type `a -> a`, the return type matches **exactly** the type of the argument. So it maps `Either a b` into an other `Either a b`. But the return type of `fmap` does **not** match exactly the second argument, even though one of its parameters doesn't change. Hence using simply `= id` wont work. Also using `all` doesn't work for the same reason: the argument has the wrong type. Haskell cannot simply generalize the type of the argument to allow what you want.

Comment: @Bakuru, yes, it makes sense, but, what happens here: `let a = Left 'a'; let b = fmap (+3) a; a == b;` => this outputs `True`, well, doesn't it make sense they work for the same types? Sorry for repeating myself again and again, I just think it could be simpler, instead of having to construct `Left a` again...

Comment: @FtheBuilder: see my answer for how to not have to construct a `Left a` again.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of explaining the type error, I have nothing to add to the previous two answers, however I'd like to mention that `Left x :: Either t a` is represented in memory the same way as `Left x :: Either t b`. What this means is that even though the type system does not let you use an `Either t a` in place of a value of type `Either t b`, for reasons already explained in perfect clarity by the other answers, you can "force" it through the type checker using `unsafeCoerce`:

```
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

instance Functor (Either t) where
  fmap f (Right a) = Right (f a)
  fmap f l         = unsafeCoerce l
```

And even though `unsafeCoerce` is generally regarded as something to avoid, if you know what you are doing, and you have a valid reason to do so, such as performance, `unsafeCoerce` can be useful in letting the compiler know you are sure the runtime value will match the expected structure.

In this case, without `unsafeCoerce`, and not considering any potential GHC optimizations, `fmap f (Left x) = Left x` would always construct a new but physically identical `Left` value, whereas the `unsafeCoerce` flavor would just return the original `Left` value with no additional memory allocations.