# Using point free style for parts of a function definition

Tags: haskell, syntax, currying, partial-application

Given this function (btw, should I say it's defined *by cases*? How do I refer to functions defined like this?),

```hs
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 0 x = x
f x _ = x
```

I'm wandering what is the reason, if one exists, why I cannot write it like this:

```hs
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 0 x = x
f = const
```

Indeed, upon trying to use this, I get this error

```
    Equations for ‘f’ have different numbers of arguments
```

which does seem obvious to me, as `f = const` is not incompatible with `f` taking two arguments (or any number of argumnts, fwiw; well, all functions take one argument and give back a function, right?).

Comment: Related to, if not a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059813/number-of-parameters-of-a-haskell-function

Comment: @chi, totally right. I'm myself voting to close.

Comment: Even though it would be *possible* to allow this, in practice, people write this by mistake more often than they try to do so on purpose, and there are good alternatives such as `LambdaCase` for pointfree definitions with multiple cases. For multiple arguments, you may like the pattern of combining `LambdaCase` with `curry`, e.g.: `curry \case { (0, x) -> x; (x, _) -> x }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no fundamental reason why it can't be done. But it complicates the language, and there's no compelling reason to do it.