# How to remove the trivial parameter?

Tags: haskell

I have a function defined as follow:

```
errorWhenNothing :: Maybe a -> M (Maybe a) -- M is a Monad
errorWhenNothing Nothing = throwError "is Nothing!"
errorWhenNothing m = return m
```

The parameter `m` seems trivial and removing it makes the function simpler and more compact. The problem is that I cannot rewrite the second definition as

```
errorWhenNothing = return
```

GHC complains `Equations for 'errorWhenNothing' have different numbers of arguments..`

I want to know is there a way to remove the `m`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah you can't have different numbers of arguments for different clauses of the same function.  It's mostly to catch the common error of leaving out a parameter on one of the lines, so instead of a confusing type error it just tells you what you did wrong straight away.

If you don't want the `m` there, you could make the wholething pointfree with the `maybe` eliminator

```
errorWhenNothing :: Maybe a -> M a
errorWhenNothing = maybe (throwError "isNothing!") return
```

whether this is an improvement is a matter of opinion.

Comment: There is also a [good semantic reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8745597/791604) to rule out differing numbers of arguments; it is not just to catch an easy error.

Comment: @DanielWagner I really don't see what it has to do with the number of arguments.  How is `foo Nothing = ... ; foo x = x` not a semantic problem in the same way with the "equation" `foo x = x`

Comment: The current rules have the following nice property: pattern matches are tried in order, yes, but once you find a pattern that matches, the equality as written is actually an equality that you can use to reason about your program. If equations with different numbers of arguments were allowed, the link shows how that property would fail: we would be able to write `foo = undefined` and have that *not* be an equality that could be used for reasoning (even when the previous patterns don't match), because the true equality would be `foo = \_ _ -> undefined`, and those two are distinguishable.

Answer (score 6):

Why return a `Maybe` from `errorWhenNothing`? If the input were `Nothing`, the computation would have been aborted with a `throwError` anyway. Having to pattern-match on the result of the function seems like needless work, because we *know* at that point that it is not `Nothing`.

Perhaps we could rewrite the function like this:

```
errorWhenNothing :: Maybe a -> M a
errorWhenNothing Nothing = throwError "is Nothing!"
errorWhenNothing (Just a) = return a
```

Now the second clause doesn't pass the parameter unchanged.